# How to stop my 16*2 lcd blink?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, code-review, code-optimization

Here I wrote code for my weighting scale measurement. In which I added an on/off switch for my LCD display. But in defined delay time my LCD is a blink and I do not want it. I want my LCD switch on/off work on 1000 delay time effectively.
How I can do this. please guide and edit my code.

```
#include "HX711.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

HX711 scale(4, 5);//(DT, SCK)
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
const int buttonPin = 2;
int buttonState = 0;

float calibration_factor = -55;
float units;
float ounces;
float in_kg;

void setup()
{
  //  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.noDisplay();
  lcd.noBacklight();

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Calculate Weight");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Loading...      ");
  delay(3000);

  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor);
  scale.tare();

}

void loop()
{
  units = scale.get_units(), 10;
  if (units < 0)
  {
    units = 0.00;
  }
  ounces = units * 0.035274;
  in_kg = units / 1000;
  
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Reading: ");
    lcd.print(in_kg);
    lcd.print("kg");

    lcd.backlight();

    // Display the text on the LCD.
    lcd.display();
    
    delay(3000);
    lcd.noDisplay();
    lcd.noBacklight();
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: If this is the same question / project as [your earlier arduino.stackexchange post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/81402/how-to-turn-on-off-with-switch-of-lcd-162) you should delete this post and edit / change your earlier post.

Comment: @st2000 I deleted the previous question. please help me with this.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  It appears the code will display the weight  value for 3 seconds and then turn off the back-light and blank the LCD.  And it sounds like you would like to change that from 3 seconds to 1 second.  Then all you have to do is change delay(3000) to delay(1000).

Comment: Don't use `lcd.backlight()` and `lcd.noBacklight()`, don't use `lcd.noDisplay()` every time your program runs the main `loop()` function. Set those things on once and leave them set.

Comment: @Dougie but I want to implement an on/off display and backlight through the switch on running device. SO how I do this?

Comment: You may need to clarify whether you're talking about an on/off that holds position or a momentary push button.  The latter meaning: push to turn on, push to turn off.